# OpenNMS custom dashboard not showing

Tags: xml, debian, opennms

I'm trying to get our OpenNMS dashboard to show one of our custom surveillance groups.
I've edited surveillance-views.xml in:

```
/etc/opennms

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<surveillance-view-configuration 
  xmlns:this="http://www.opennms.org/xsd/config/surveillance-views" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opennms.org/xsd/config/surveillance-views http://www.opennms.org/xsd/config/surveillance-views.xsd"
  default-view="default" >
<views >
 <view name="default" refresh-seconds="300" >
   <rows>
     <row-def label="Routers" >
       <category name="Routers"/>
     </row-def>
     <row-def label="Switches" >
       <category name="Switches" />
     </row-def>
     <row-def label="Servers" >
       <category name="Servers" />
     </row-def>
     <row-def label="Zinwave">
       <category name="zinwave">
     </row-def>
   </rows>
  <columns>
    <column-def label="PROD" >
      <category name="Production" />
    </column-def>
    <column-def label="TEST" >
      <category name="Test" />
    </column-def>
    <column-def label="DEV" >
      <category name="Development" />
    </column-def>
  </columns>
</view>
```

The row Zinwave however doesn't show up on the dashboard. The surveillance group zinwave exists and has 2 devices in it. There are no users with a defined custom dashboard, so everyone should see the default.

Can anyone explain me why I'm not seeing the Zinwave group on my dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in:

```
<category name="zinwave">
```

this should be:

```
<category name="zinwave" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to include devices you would like to be shown on the dashboard.
Check under

Admin-> Manage Surveillance Category -> zinwave and add zinwave devices.

Be default OpenNMS should insert all category that you create on the Surveillance Category, but if it doesn't work try to remove the zinwave category from Surveillance Categories. Then recreate it and add the device again. (Also restart OpenNMS, it helps).

Please check also that there's no typo error on you code. Surveillance categories can be different from categories, but I would use the same name if possibile (to avoid any misunderstanding). So please check also if a capital z is needed in the code below, or not

```
<row-def label="Zinwave">
       <category name="zinwave">
</row-def>
```